# Determinant of block matrix - Finding a field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Find a field F and matrices $A,B, C, D \in F^{n,n}$ such that

$$ \text{det}\bigg(\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
A & B \\
C & D \end{array} \right]\bigg) \neq \text{det}(A) \ \text{det}(D) - \text{det}(B) \ \text{det}(C)$$

I thought to consider if A is invertible and $AC = CA$, or [other cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), but these formulars are all driven from the one above.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, look for a matrix that has mostly zeros.  The following example applies to any field, so taking $\Bbb F = \Bbb R$ is certainly okay:
$$
M = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
\hline
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0
\end{array}
\right]
$$